# Moving all documents in a collection from mongo to azure blob storage

Tags: mongodb, azure, mongodb-query, azure-storage

I am trying to move all documents in a mongo collection to a azure blob storage within a scheduled azure webjob using c# and mongo 1.9.1 drivers.

I do not want to hold all the 100000 documents in memory in the webjob. Is there a better way may be like a batched retrieve of documents from mongo? Or is there a completely different approach that I can look into?

Answer (score 2):

You could have one web job process responsible for queuing up each document individually. This web job would only need the unique identifier for each document so that it could push that as a message to an Azure Storage Queue. You can have this web job configured to be scheduled or manual depending on the need.

Then have another web job that migrates a single file. You can have this web job setup to be continuous so that as long as there are messages on the queue to be read, it will start processing them. By default a web job will parallelize 16 items off of a queue. This is configurable.